# Android runtime exception "Could not find class" in the same package as found classes

Tags: android, eclipse

I get a runtime exception "Could not find class..." for a class that is in the same package as the main activity that starts running. See logcat below.

My main activity starts to run properly, then a fragment "MyFragment", which is defined in the same package as the MainActivity can not be found.

```
07-09 22:03:15.876: E/dalvikvm(30826): Could not find class 'com.x.MyFragment', referenced from method com.x.MainActivity.onCreate
...
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826): Process: com.x, PID: 30826
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.x.MyFragment
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at com.x.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:192)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
07-09 22:03:16.061: E/AndroidRuntime(30826):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

FWIW, this is code that has run for a very long time, until I had to re-install Eclipse after the Google ADT 23 problems.

Please help.

Comment: Uninstall the app, clean the project, then run it again

Comment: Good idea, but that didn't do it, thanks.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles into here, I just switched to Android Studio.  I lost a week doing it, but it's better in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your Project

Project -> Clean then either select your package or just click on clean all.

Then rebuild the project.

Sometimes I have gotten strange errors like this due to me running something.

Also look in the fragment itself for things that are either depreciated or missing after the update.

Good luck

Comment: What do you mean exactly?  Everything compiles just fine, how would I determine if something is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Right click on project > Android Tools > Fix Project properties
2. Project > Clean

then again run the project.

Comment: Have you checked error log. May be there are chances with any error in xml file. Could you post error/warnings. Check the "Problems" view in eclipse to find other errors.